# How to set a proxy using phpunit and selenium2?

Tags: proxy, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I cant find example with PHPunit. I don't know what function i suppose to use. there are a lot examples for java but i cant find nothing for PHPUnit.
I opened the `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html` 
and in capabilities there aren't settings for a proxy.
When i used the function setDesiredCapabilities the selenium always opened IE. Below are my "code"

```
class testtest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase {



protected function setUp()
{

     $capabilities=array('browser' => 'firefox');
     $this->setDesiredCapabilities($capabilities);
     $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.test.com/');

 }

 public function testvvatg()
 {
     $this->url('http://www.test.com');
     $url=$this->title();
     $this->assertEquals('asdf', $url);
 }
}
```

Please help thanks

Answer (score 1):

While this topic is old, I found it while googling for a solution to the problem, so I figured I'd contribute.

Reading the source of PHPUnit Selenium2TestCase, you can see [a link to the format that setDesiredCapabilities requires](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol). In particular, you'd want the [Proxy JSON Object format](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#Proxy_JSON_Object).

For example:

```
$this->setDesiredCapabilities(array(
    "proxy" => array(
        "proxyType" => "manual",
        "httpProxy" => "proxyhost.com:1337",
        "noProxy" => "dontproxy.me/please" //This one is undocumented. I'm not sure how to specify more than one
    )
));
```